# .xib file location

Tags: xcode, xcode4.5

I am literally following a iOS Programming book (iOS5). it says that there is a xib file in the navigator but I am unable to find it. I am using xcode 4.5. I am really confused as this is my first time trying out iPhone development or anything in xCode if that matters.

Comment: When you created the project, did you select "use storyboard"?

Comment: Yes I did and the storyboard is there

Comment: Then there is your answer. If you ask for a storyboard, the template will include one storyboard and no nib(.xib)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on which kind of project you are creating. For example a project created from the "single view application" template will create a xib file.

Comment: Ramy the navigator is on and hence I said I couldn't find it IN the navigator. I know the file should be there, but it simply isn't and this with every new project.

Comment: What kind of project do you choose in templates?

Comment: I create single view application

Comment: If you check " use storyboards" you will have a .storyboard file instead of .xib , uncheck " use storyboards".